# Ubuntu 18.04 dual monitor issue

Tags: 18.04, hdmi, cinnamon, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop (Ubuntu 18.04 + cinnamon) and I connect a monitor with HDMI to it so that I'm using dual screen view.

I move several windows to the monitor and then unplug the monitor (all the windows are on the laptop now). But when I reconnect the monitor, all those windows remain on the laptop screen and my monitor stays blank.

This was working with Ubuntu 16.04, but now with Ubuntu 18.04 it doesn't.